# Which way should i choose for shell command parsing?

Tags: c, shell, pipe, io-redirection

For my studies I have to make a shell in C

I want to parse a shell command

My function `parse_sequence` output a command_t * which is a struct containing:

```c
char *program_name;
int fd_input;
bool override;
int fd_output;
bool heredoc_mode;
char **args;
command_t *next; // kind of linked_list
```

What i call sequence is a command with redirections and pipes

Sequences are cut by `&&`, `||` and `;`

`ls > file | sort` is a single sequence where `ls && echo OK` is formed of two sequences

I hesitate between two ways of achieve parsing

consider this as pseudo code

**first way**: recursion

```c
command_t *parse_sequence(char *sequence)
{
    command_t *ret = malloc(sizeof(command_t));
    char **tokens = split(sequence);
    int i = 0;

    while (tokens[i]) {
        if (!strcmp(commands[i], "<")) {
            // set input file (open commands[i + 1])
        }
        if (!strcmp(commands[i], ">")) {
            // set output file (open commands[i + 1])
        }
        if (!strcmp(commands[i], "|")) {
            // recursion: ret->next = parse_sequence(tokens[i + 1]);
        }
        else {
            if (i == 0)
                // set program name
            else
                // append args 
        }
    }
    return (ret);
}
```

**example**: `ls > file | sort --rev`

```
i == 0: ls is set as program_name
i == 1: ++i (file) is opened and set as output file descriptor (using dup2)
i == 3: *recursion and setup pipe*
// in the recursive call commands[0] is "sort"
(recursion) i == 0: set program name
(recursion) i == 1: append argument "--rev"
(recursion) i == 2: exit function because commands[i] == NULL
```

**second way**: split each command with pipe as delimiter

```c
command_t *parse_sequence(char *sequence)
{
    command_t *ret = malloc(sizeof(command_t));
    command_t current_command = ret;
    char **tokens = split_tokens(sequence, (char **){"|", NULL});
    int i = 0;

    while (commands[i]) {
        if (!strcmp(commands[i], "<")) {
            // set input file (open commands[++i])
        }
        if (!strcmp(commands[i], ">")) {
            // set output file (open commands[++i])
        }
        if (!strcmp(commands[i], "|") // tokens are kept when splitting
            // setup pipe
            // current_command = current_command->next
            // i++
        else {
            if (i > 0 && commands[i - 1] pipe or redirection)
                // set program name
            else
                // append args 
        }

    }
    return (ret);
}
```

**example**: `ls > file | sort --rev`

```
i == 0: ls is set as program_name
i == 1: ++i (file) is opened and set as output file descriptor (using dup2)
i == 3: *setup pipe* and current_command = current_command->next
i == 4: set program name
i == 5: append argument "--rev"
i == 6: exit function because commands[i] == NULL
```

Which one of the two ways is the best ?
What problems will I encounter ?

I know my examples are incorrect in tcsh but that's not important for my question

I have few time so I want the fastest way to implement

Thank you !

Comment: `ls > file | sort` is considered an ambiguous redirect in `csh`.  I guess `sh` just redirects `ls` to `file` and sends an EOF to `sort`, which seems pretty useless.

Comment: so the left part of a pipe can't have output redirection ?

and the right part of a pipe can't have input redirection ?


seems logic


zsh write `ls` output to file and send it to the pipe but tcsh raise error


the reference shell for the school project is tcsh so i will haev to check for that

Also, I will update my example

Comment: What you're asking for is something called `tee`.  It's a utility that essentially does that for you, writing stdin to both a file and stdout, e.g. `ls | tee file | sort`.  I don't know of any shell that automatically does it though.  Even the shells that don't give an error don't do it (`sh`, `bash`, ...)  They simply direct the output to the file and send nothing through the pipe.  I suggest giving an error in that case, unless you want to automatically implement `tee` into your shell.

Comment: try `ls > file | sort --rev > rev_file` in zsh and cat both files

Comment: `zsh` isn't part of the standard Ubuntu distribution so I don't use it (although I do install csh/tcsh).  It sounds like maybe they built `tee` into the shell.  I still prefer to make it explicit, since 90% of the time that would be an unintended user error that you'd want to catch.

Comment: Note that strings are going to complicate your parsing scheme in due course: ```echo "<html><head><title>Pipe '|'</title></head><body><h1>Pipe '|'</h1></body></html>" | tr 'a-z' '][}{!@#$%^&*()_+=,./?;:`~|'``` is going to send things into a tizzy if you are not careful.

Comment: Also remember that you can write `ls >file` as well as `ls > file` (and, indeed, `>file ls` — and there's someone at work who wrote shell script containing something like `<head> file cat` which redirects input from a file `head` and sends the output to a file `file` via the command `cat`).